Do dictionaries have the same implicit line continuation as parentheses?
I was surprised that this seems to work without parentheses:
dict = {
    "a": 1 if True
        else 2,
    "b": 2
}

I know that dictionaries have implicit line continuation, but I presumed that only let you split between commas. Does it simply function like parentheses, where everything is treated as one line?

Yes, implicit line continuation/joining takes place within parentheses, square brackets and curly braces in Python as documented:

Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be
split over more than one physical line without using backslashes.

